# Enumerating all paths from root to leaf given a dfs ordering of a directed acyclic graph

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost

Given the following graph:

[image]

usage of `boost` gives the following dfs enumeration of the graph:

```
order of discovery:  0  1  2  3  4  5  6 
order of finish:  2  3  1  0  6  5  4
```

The code that produces that is:

**bgl.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/depth_first_search.hpp>
#include <boost/range/irange.hpp>
#include <boost/pending/indirect_cmp.hpp>

using namespace boost;

typedef adjacency_list_traits<vecS, vecS, directedS> Traits;

typedef adjacency_list<
    vecS, vecS, directedS,

    property<
        vertex_name_t, std::string,
        property<vertex_index_t, int,
        property<vertex_color_t, boost::default_color_type,
        property<vertex_distance_t, double,
        property<vertex_predecessor_t, Traits::edge_descriptor> 
    > > > >,

    property<
        edge_index_t, int,
        property<edge_capacity_t, double,
        property<edge_weight_t, double,
        property<edge_residual_capacity_t, double,
        property<edge_reverse_t, Traits::edge_descriptor>
    > > > > >
    Graph;

typedef graph_traits < Graph >::vertices_size_type size_type;

template < typename TimeMap > class dfs_time_visitor:public default_dfs_visitor {
  typedef typename property_traits < TimeMap >::value_type T;
public:
  dfs_time_visitor(TimeMap dmap, TimeMap fmap, T & t)
:  m_dtimemap(dmap), m_ftimemap(fmap), m_time(t) {
  }
  template < typename Vertex, typename Graph >
    void discover_vertex(Vertex u, const Graph & g) const
  {
    put(m_dtimemap, u, m_time++);
  }
  template < typename Vertex, typename Graph >
    void finish_vertex(Vertex u, const Graph & g) const
  {
    put(m_ftimemap, u, m_time++);
  }
  TimeMap m_dtimemap;
  TimeMap m_ftimemap;
  T & m_time;
};

typedef
    iterator_property_map<std::vector<size_type>::iterator,
                          property_map<Graph, vertex_index_t>::const_type>
    time_pm_type;

class Dfsgraph{
public:
    void addvertex();
    void addedge(int f, int t);
    void rundfs();
private:
    Graph g;
    std::vector < size_type > dtime;
    std::vector < size_type > ftime;
};
```

**bgl.cpp**

```
#include "bgl.h"
#include <stdio.h>//for printf

void Dfsgraph::addvertex(){
    add_vertex(g);
    dtime.push_back(0);
    ftime.push_back(0);
}

void Dfsgraph::addedge(int f, int to){
    add_edge(f, to, g);
}

void Dfsgraph::rundfs(){
  time_pm_type dtime_pm(dtime.begin(), get(vertex_index, g));
  time_pm_type ftime_pm(ftime.begin(), get(vertex_index, g));
  size_type t = 0;
  dfs_time_visitor < time_pm_type >vis(dtime_pm, ftime_pm, t);

  depth_first_search(g, visitor(vis));

  // use std::sort to order the vertices by their discover time
  std::vector < size_type > discover_order(num_vertices(g));
  integer_range < size_type > r(0, num_vertices(g));
  std::copy(r.begin(), r.end(), discover_order.begin());
  std::sort(discover_order.begin(), discover_order.end(),
            indirect_cmp < time_pm_type, std::less < size_type > >(dtime_pm));
  printf("order of discovery: ");
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < num_vertices(g); ++i)
    printf(" %d ", discover_order[i]);

  std::vector < size_type > finish_order(num_vertices(g));
  std::copy(r.begin(), r.end(), finish_order.begin());
  std::sort(finish_order.begin(), finish_order.end(),indirect_cmp < time_pm_type, std::less < size_type > >(ftime_pm));
  printf("\norder of finish: ");
  for (i = 0; i < num_vertices(g); ++i)
    printf(" %d ", finish_order[i]);
  printf("\n");

}

int main(){
    Dfsgraph g;
    for(int nd = 0; nd < 7; nd++)
        g.addvertex();
    g.addedge(0,1); 
    g.addedge(1,2);
    g.addedge(1,3);
    g.addedge(4,5);
    g.addedge(5,3);
    g.addedge(5,6);

    g.rundfs();

    return 0;

}
```

I would like to enumerate all complete paths from root nodes (those that do not have an incoming arc) to the respective leaf nodes (those that do not have an outgoing arc). That is, I would like to enumerate:

```
0->1->2
0->1->3
4->5->3
4->5->6
```

Q1. Is this possible using ready-made library functions offered by `boost`?

Q2. If not, what are efficient ways of doing it from scratch?

Comment: I can't answer the question about boost. If you can modify the recursive `dfs()`  search function, it's easy. Pass another parameter to `dfs()` - a stack which contains the nodes visited so far in the current; push an element before calling the `dfs()` recursively, and pop the last element of the stack after returning from the recursive call. When a leaf node is reached, simply print that stack.

Comment: @kfx it is unclear to me whether 4->5->3 would feature in the method you propose since 3 is reached prior to encountering 5.

Comment: You need to run DFS from each root node. Start with an array of roots.